# How to get starting value and end value of particular transcation

Tags: sql

input :

```
+------+------------+--------------+------------+
| NAME | Date       | Amount_start | Amount_END |
+------+------------+--------------+------------+
| AAA  | 2016-10-06 |      20      |      4     |
| AAA  | 2016-10-07 |      30      |      6     |
| AAA  | 2016-10-08 |       7      |      8     |
| AAA  | 2016-10-09 |     380      |      9     |
| ...  | ...        |     ...      |    ...     |
| ZZZ  | 2016-10-06 |      10      |     20     |
| ZZZ  | 2016-10-07 |      11      |      6     |
+------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

output:

```
+------+--------------+------------+
| NAME | Amount_start | Amount_END |
+------+--------------+------------+
| AAA  |       20     |      9     |
| ...  |      ...     |    ...     |
| ZZZ  |       10     |      6     |
+------+--------------+------------+
```

output : In one row need to take Amount_start of starting date and 
    Amount_end of End date of that employee

Comment: you forgot "or postgresql" @DaleBurrell ;) I've removed all these conflicting tags on this post. When you edit your post to include the tag for the RDBMS you are using, and **only** the RDBMS you are using, please add a question to your question (seems like a silly thing to say, but you haven't asked one here). Also, when you ask the question please show us your attempts and explain why didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't had a go, then I suggest (if this was SQL Server) `ROW_NUMBER` and some conditional aggregation. The answer will likely be very similar for the other RDBMS, but knowing which one is really important here as none of them have the same syntax, nor support the same parts of the ISO standards.

Comment: Please take a look at Larnu's comments.  You should state what you tried and ask a question.  If you have two entries for AAA with the same date, how do you determine the sequence? There is no inherent order in SQL data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.name,
       max(case when seqnum_a = 1 then amount_start end) as amount_start,
       max(case when seqnum_d = 1 then amount_end end) as amount_end
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date asc) as seqnum_a,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum_d
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```